# Does $(p-1)^2$ divide $\det[(\frac{i^2+cij+dj^2}p)]_{0\le i,j\le p-1}$ when $(\frac dp)=-1$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, determinants, binary-quadratic-forms, quadratic-residues

Let $p$ be an odd prime. As in [my paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1071579718301539?via%3Dihub), for $c,d\in\mathbb Z$ let us define
$$[c,d]_p:=\det\left[\left(\frac{i^2+cij+dj^2}p\right)\right]_{0\le i,j\le p-1},$$
where $(\frac{\cdot}p)$ is the Legendre symbol.
By Theorem 1.3 of the paper, if $(\frac dp)=1$ then 
$$[c,d]_p\equiv0\pmod{p-1}.$$
It is interesting to study $[c,d]_p$ in the case $(\frac dp)=-1$. Here I pose two new conjectures.

**Conjecture 1.** For any odd prime $p$ and $c,d\in\mathbb Z$ with $(\frac dp)=-1$, we have $(p-1)^2\mid[c,d]_p$.

*Remark* 1. I have verified this conjecture for all odd primes $p<750$. Moreover, I conjecture that for any positive odd integer $n$ and integer $d$ with $(\frac dn)=-1$, we have
$$\det\left[\left(\frac{i^2+cij+dj^2}n\right)\right]_{0\le i,j\le n-1}\equiv0\pmod{\varphi(n)^2},$$
where $(\frac{\cdot}n)$ is the Jacobi symbol and $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function. This extended version has been verified for positive odd integers $n<200$.

**Conjecture 2.** (i) For any prime $p\equiv5\pmod 8$ with $p=x^2+y^2$ $ (x,y\in\mathbb Z\ \&\ 4\mid x-1)$, the number $[3,2]_p/((p-1)^2x)$ is a square.

(ii) For any prime $p\equiv3\pmod 8$ with $p=x^2+2y^2$ $(x,y\in\mathbb Z\ \&\ 4\mid x-1)$, there is a nonnegative integer $a_p$ such that 
$$[4,2]_p=-[8,8]_p=(-1)^{(p-3)/8}2^{p-3}(p-1)^2a_p^2\,x.$$

(iii) For any prime $p\equiv7\pmod{12}$ with $p=x^2+3y^2$ ($x,y\in\mathbb Z\ \&\ 3\mid x-1)$, the number $[3,3]_p/(2^{(p-7)/2}(p-1)^2x)$ is a square.

(iv) For any prime $p\equiv 11,15,23\pmod{28}$ with $p=x^2+7y^2$ ($x,y\in\mathbb Z\ \&\ (\frac x7)=1)$, the number $-[21,112]_p/((p-1)^2x)$ is a square.

(v) For any odd prime $p\equiv 1,2,4\pmod 7$ with $p=x^2+7y^2$ ($x,y\in\mathbb Z\ \&\ (\frac x7)=1)$, the number
$(-1)^{(p-1)/2}[42,-7]_p/(8(p-1)x)$ is a square.

*Remark* 2. I have verified Conjecture 2 for odd primes $p<2000$.

For some related published conjectures and results, see Conjecture 4.8 in [my paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1071579718301539?via%3Dihub) and the preprint [arXiv:1812.08080](http://arxiv.org/abs/1812.08080).

Conjecture 2 looks quite challenging, but Conjecture 1 might be relatively easy. Your comments are welcome!